# In Vue router, why would this happen? this$1.pending !== route

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-router

In most cases, when I use `this.$router.push()` everything works fine. However, there is one case where I'm doing that that throws an exception. The page changes just fine - it is just that the message `vue-router.esm.js?8c4f:2007 Uncaught (in promise)` appears in the console.

I don't see anything different in the way I call this particular route than any other.

The code below is where it fails in the router. `this$1.pending1` and `route` are both objects. I put a breakpoint there and checked the following: `JSON.stringify(this$1.pending) === JSON.stringify(route)` and that returns true, so they have identical data.

In javascript, objects are not considered equal unless they are the same, but I don't know why, in this case, the object is a clone instead of being identical.

```
  runQueue(queue, iterator, function () {
    var postEnterCbs = [];
    var isValid = function () { return this$1.current === route; };
    // wait until async components are resolved before
    // extracting in-component enter guards
    var enterGuards = extractEnterGuards(activated, postEnterCbs, isValid);
    var queue = enterGuards.concat(this$1.router.resolveHooks);
    runQueue(queue, iterator, function () {
      if (this$1.pending !== route) { // EXCEPTION ON THIS LINE
        return abort()
      }
      this$1.pending = null;
      onComplete(route);
      if (this$1.router.app) {
        this$1.router.app.$nextTick(function () {
          postEnterCbs.forEach(function (cb) {
            cb();
          });
        });
      }
    });
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

This isn't exactly an answer, but here's a discussion of other people who have run into the same thing: https://github.com/vuejs/vue-router/issues/2932

It doesn't sound like there is a resolution, but since it appears harmless, (except for the message in the console), I'm going to not worry about it at the moment.